# Practicing buffer overflow attack in Ubuntu

Tags: memory, ubuntu, random

I am trying to learn to use buffer overflow attack in Ubuntu. Unfortunately, I cannot turn off Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) feature in this OS, which is turned on by default. I have tried some work around found in some fedora books:

```
echo "0" > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

but for some reason the protection's still there. Please give me some suggestions. Thanks.

[edit]Actually the above command was not successful, it said "Permission Denied", even with sudo. How can I fix that?

[adding] I kept on getting segmetation fault error when it shows an address in stack. Is it related to non-executable stack in ubuntu :(?

Comment: You need execstack (apt-get install execstack) to disable NX on a per-app basis.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194666/disable-randomization-of-memory-addresses

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need root perms before attempting it, and if I'm not mistaken, to restart once you've done it.

```
 sudo -i
 echo "0" > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

Comment: I have tried it as you said, but after restarting ubuntu I viewed that file and the previous value in that file was unchanged :|. Thanks.

Comment: Of course it changed back after reboot; /proc is a volatile directory. Try recompiling the kernel with randomize_va_space turned off :)

Comment: Thank you for answering this, it is going to come in handy in the next couple of days.

Comment: @wakandan - I believe "restart" refers to your program, not ubuntu. When you restart ubuntu, the protection is set to it's initial value (enabled).

Answer (score 2):

found it myself

you have to compile this way:

gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o OUTPUT INPUT.c

Answer (score 1):

gcc compile with `-fno-stack-protector`

Answer (score 1):

to echo to files with root acces using sudo you can use the following code:

```
echo "0" | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off ASLR for a particular process by launching with setarch

For 32 bit programs:

```
setarch i386 -R yourProgram
```

For 64 bit programs:

```
setarch x86_64 -R yourProgram
```