# Getting User Input and storing into elements in Structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am currently writing a simple code that repeatedly reads user input and store the input into a structure, subsequently printing them out. I encounter a problem while reading "accountNum" and "balance". The warning the compiler gave was due to the type of different arguments expected. (*int/*double vs int/double).
I tried using gets() but to no avail. I am hoping to get an understanding on this.

Also, am I accessing the elements correctly during the print function? Thanks in advance!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct account
{
    struct
    {
        char lastName[10];
        char firstName[10];
    } names;
    int accountNum;
    double balance;
};

void nextCustomer(struct account *acct);
void printCustomer(struct account acct);

int main()
{
    struct account record;
    int flag = 0;
    do
    {
        nextCustomer(&record);
        if ((strcmp(record.names.firstName, "End") == 0) && (strcmp(record.names.lastName, "Customer") == 0))
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
        if (flag != 1)
        {
            printCustomer(record);
        }
    }
    while (flag != 1);
}

void nextCustomer(struct account *acct)
{
    printf("Enter names: (firstName lastName): " );
    scanf("%s%s", acct->names.firstName, acct->names.lastName);
    printf("Enter account number: ");
    scanf("%d", &acct->accountNum);
    printf("Enter balance : ");
    scanf("%lf", &acct->balance);
}

void printCustomer(struct account acct)
{
    printf("%s%s %d %lf", acct.names.firstName, acct.names.lastName ,acct.accountNum,acct.balance);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get the `int` and the `double`

   ```
   scanf("%d", &acct->accountNum);
   scanf("%lf", &acct->balance);
   ```

   `&acct->accountNum` is a pointer to `int` and 
      `&acct->balance` is a pointer to `double`
2. In the second `scanf` you had forgotten `'%'`.
3. It is not recommended to use `gets()` for any purpose and it is now considered a deprecated function. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5068460/1413133)

Comment: Ah i see! Does that mean I should add "&" for the string scanf too? But why is it working fine without it?

Comment: When you pass a string to a function it decays to a pointer. e.g. `acct->names.firstName` appears to be of type `char*`. So you don't have to and shouldn't use & for the string. But be aware of the size of the buffer, if it's big enough for the input.