# Disable randomization of memory addresses

Tags: linux, memory-address, aslr

I'm trying to debug a binary that uses a lot of pointers. Sometimes for seeing output quickly to figure out errors, I print out the address of objects and their corresponding values, however, the object addresses are randomized and this defeats the purpose of this quick check up. 
Is there a way to disable this temporarily/permanently so that I get the same values every time I run the program.

Oops. OS is `Linux fsttcs1 2.6.32-28-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 10 23:42:43 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238457/disable-and-re-enable-address-space-layout-randomization-only-for-myself

Answer (score 52, accepted):

On Ubuntu , it can be disabled with...

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

On Windows, this post might be of some help...

http://blog.didierstevens.com/2007/11/20/quickpost-another-funny-vista-trick-with-aslr/

Comment: Thanks. This was a life saver debugging an application so I gave you an extra 50.

Answer (score 45):

To temporarily disable ASLR for a particular program you can always issue the following (no need for sudo)

```
setarch `uname -m` -R ./yourProgram
```

Comment: I found that `setarch` finds the output of `uname -m` disagreeable on ARM systems (e.g. Raspberry Pi).  But `setarch linux32 -R ./yourProgram` works great.

Comment: A nice variant is `setarch \`uname -m\` -R $SHELL`.  That spawns a shell with ASLR disabled, and any command you run from that shell will also have ASLR disabled.

Comment: Oh nice! I like that a lot!

Answer (score 10):

You can also do this programmatically from C source before a UNIX `exec`.

If you take a look at the sources for [setarch](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setarch) (here's one source):

http://code.metager.de/source/xref/linux/utils/util-linux/sys-utils/setarch.c

You can see if boils down to a system call (`syscall`) or a function call (depending on what your system defines).  From setarch.c:

```
#ifndef HAVE_PERSONALITY
# include <syscall.h>
# define personality(pers) ((long)syscall(SYS_personality, pers))
#endif
```

On my CentOS 6 64-bit system, it looks like it uses a function (which probably calls the self-same syscall above).  Take a look at this snippet from the include file in `/usr/include/sys/personality.h` (as referenced as  `<sys/personality.h>` in the setarch source code):

```
/* Set different ABIs (personalities).  */
extern int personality (unsigned long int __persona) __THROW;
```

What it boils down to, is that you can, from C code, call and set the personality to use ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE and then `exec` (just like `setarch` does).

```
#include <sys/personality.com>

#ifndef HAVE_PERSONALITY
# include <syscall.h>
# define personality(pers) ((long)syscall(SYS_personality, pers))
#endif

...

void mycode() 
{
   // If requested, turn off the address rand feature right before execing
   if (MyGlobalVar_Turn_Address_Randomization_Off) {
     personality(ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE);
   } 
   execvp(argv[0], argv); // ... from set-arch.
}
```

It's pretty obvious you can't turn address randomization off in the process you are in (grin: unless maybe dynamic loading), so this only affects forks and execs later.  I believe the Address Randomization flags are inherited by child sub-processes?

Anyway, that's how you can programmatically turn off the address randomization in C source code.  This may be your only solution if you don't want the force a user to intervene manually and start-up with setarch or one of the other solutions listed earlier.

Before you complain about security issues in turning this off, some shared memory libraries/tools (such as [PickingTools shared memory](http://www.picklingtools.com/html/shm.html) and some [IBM databases](http://db2commerce.com/2012/10/02/how-to-disable-aslr-and-why-you-should-do-it/)) need to be able to turn off randomization of memory addresses.