# Disable and re-enable address space layout randomization only for myself

Tags: linux, bash, aslr, virtual-address-space, sysctl

I would like to disable address space layout randomization (ASLR) on my system (Ubuntu Gnu/Linux 2.6.32-41-server), but, if I use

```
sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0
```

the change would affect all users on the system, I presume.  (Is this true?)  How can I limit the effects of disabling ASLR to myself as a user only, or only to the shell session in which I invoke the command to disable?

BTW, I see that my system's current (default) setting is

```
kernel.randomize_va_space = 2
```

Why 2 and not 1 or 3?  Where can I find documentation about the numerical values of /proc/sys settings, their ranges, and their meanings?  Thanks!

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Randomization says that `setarch $(uname -m) -RL bash` must work

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15881/disable-address-space-layout-randomization-aslr-for-my-processes || http://askubuntu.com/questions/318315/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-aslr-address-space-layout-randomization

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The documentation for the `randomize_va_space` **sysctl** setting is in [`Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt) in the kernel source tree. Basically,

> 0 - Turn the process address space randomization off.
>
> 1 - Make the addresses of mmap base, stack and VDSO page randomized.
>
> 2 - Additionally enable heap randomization.

Comment: Thanks!  That does address my second ("BTW") question above, but I still don't see a way to restrict the effect of sysctl to a single account or shell session.  I guess it must be impossible. :-/

Comment: Yes, the setting is global.  A quick grep shows that there is some (maybe vestigial) code in the "personality" code (handling multiple ABIs) that can do the converse.  Setting ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE flag on the personality field of a task_struct will disable the behavior even when it is globally enabled.  But that's probably more kernel voodoo than you want to deal with.

Answer (score 37):

The best way to disable locally the ASLR on a Linux-based system is to use processes personality flags. The command to manipulate personality flags is [`setarch`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setarch.8.html) with

> `-R`, `--addr-no-randomize`
>
> Disables randomization of the virtual address space (turns on ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE).

Here is how to proceed:

```
$> setarch $(uname -m) -R /bin/bash
```

This command runs a shell in which the ASLR has been disabled. All descendants of this process will inherit of the personality flags of the father and thus have a disabled ASLR. The only way to break the inheritance of the flags would be to call a setuid program (it would be a security breach to support such feature).

Note that the `uname -m` is here to not hard-code the architecture of your platform and make this command portable.

You can check that it worked by hitting the following command several times:

```
#> cat /proc/self/maps
```

If the memory mapping stay the same, then ASLR has been disabled. If not, then you probably did something wrong.

Comment: How do I check if it worked? Any command to print out the settings?

Comment: Good question, I added a way to check it worked (it is true that I always check it worked like this but I did not mentioned it).

Comment: "You can check that it worked by hitting the following command several times". Just to be clear I have to `restart program -> cat /proc/self/maps` multiple times right?

Comment: In fact, you do not need to restart the program. The command `cat /proc/self/maps` is just displaying the memory mapping of the `cat` program itself (it is a self reference to it and `cat` is sending it to `stdout`). If the memory mapping is changing between two runs, then the ASLR is still enabled. If it stays static, then it is disabled.