# pmap result shows many file are mapped from virtual address zero

Tags: linux

For init process, pid is 1, and some other processes, when use pmap to show their mmapped file, results show like this:

```
0000000000000000      0K r-x--  /sbin/init
0000000000000000      0K r----  /sbin/init
0000000000000000      0K rw---  /sbin/init
0000000000000000      0K -----    [ stack ]
0000000000000000      0K rw---    [ stack ]
0000000000000000      0K r-x--  /lib/libc-2.12.2.so
0000000000000000      0K -----  /lib/libc-2.12.2.so
0000000000000000      0K r----  /lib/libc-2.12.2.so
0000000000000000      0K rw---  /lib/libc-2.12.2.so
0000000000000000      0K rw---    [ stack ]
0000000000000000      0K r-x--  /lib/ld-2.12.2.so
0000000000000000      0K rw---    [ stack ]
0000000000000000      0K rw---    [ stack ]
0000000000000000      0K r-x--    [ stack ]
0000000000000000      0K rw---  /lib/ld-2.12.2.so
0000000000000000      0K rw---    [ stack ]
0000000000000000      0K rw---    [ stack ]
ffffffffff600000      4K r----    [ anon ]
 total                4K
```

why this happens? all virtual address except last one start from zero and size is zero.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238457/disable-and-re-enable-address-space-layout-randomization-only-for-mysef). It sounds like you have disabled address space randomization.

Comment: But I use `sysctl -A` to find out that kernel.randomize_va_space = 2