# How to disable address randomization (ASLR) from an ELF file?

Tags: linux, random, elf, objdump, aslr

**Solved:**
The solution was calling personality(0x40000). See details below in the comments.

Where does the ASLR flag resides within an ELF file? I need to disable ASLR for a specific library (.so).
I've tried using objdump but I couldn't find out how to do so.

I can't use /proc because it doesn't appear to work on my Android 4.4.4,
so I'm trying to modify the binary.

**Edit:**
I've compiled the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void* getEIP()
{
    return __builtin_return_address(0) - 0x5;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("EIP located at: %p\n", getEIP());
    return 0;
}
```

without ASLR (PIE):

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe code.c -o noPIE --sysroot=%NDK%\platforms\android-3\arch-arm
```

with ASLR (PIE):

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe -fPIE -pie code.c -o withPIE --sysroot=%NDK%\platforms\android-3\arch-arm
```

The noPIE binary indeed isn't being randomized, even though:

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
2
```

Comment: AFAIK, the ASLR flag does not reside inside the ELF file. It is a dynamic property of the kernel. So if you cannot use `/proc/`, I believe you are stuck. BTW, I might be widely wrong! See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5194666/841108). And ASLR is a process-wide property of the address space so changing it only for one particular `libfoo.so` does not make any sense

Comment: Perhaps I should've mentioned - I can't use /proc because it doesn't work on my Android 4.4. It simply doesn't really disable ASLR. What did work for me was compiling without ASLR. Do you know any workaround?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain how you are compiling without ASLR....

Comment: I used -fPIE and -pie which I assume one of them simply generates position independent code and the other sets the ASLR flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to disable ASLR for a specific library (.so).

You *can't* (and the ASLR does not reside anywhere in the ELF file because it's not a property of the ELF, it's a property of the kernel).

What you *can* do is disable randomization for a given process. `setarch -R` is [your friend](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setarch.8.html).

Comment: This works. I didn't have setarch on my android device so I used personality:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html

I didn't find any macro to disable ASLR so I used strace like Basile Starynkevitch said on ubuntu and found out it passes 0x40000.

Comment: Actually you *can*. You can make nonrelocatable .so files (klibc's so is nonrelacatable).

Answer (score 2):

I believe [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is happening in both cases. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5194666/841108).

But in the first case (`noPIE` binary), the executable *itself* is having a fixed address; however all the calls to  [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) without `MAP_FIXED` are randomized, and this includes the loading of the shared libraries.

In the second case (`PIE` binary), even the executable itself is loaded at some random address by [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (and also of course the shared libraries, which are later `mmap`-ed by [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html) mentioned as the "interpreter" inside your ELF files).

You could check by [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)-ing both executions.

ASLR is part of the kernel state. Chaning it for `mmap`-ing a particular shared object does not make any sense, but, as [Employed Russian answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33093725/841108), you could disable it with `setarch -R` for a process and its future child processes (perhaps your parent shell and all its children).

Comment: No calls to mmap will map at the address specified in the first argument if possible and non-zero.