# Is there any significance to the address of argc when performing buffer overflows?

Tags: c, gdb, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow, exploit

I am working through the Stack buffer overflows on Protostar and my end goal is to get a better understanding of what is happening. I am on exercise 4 (https://exploit.education/protostar/stack-four/). I got my buffer overflow to execute the function desired but I can only do it in gdb. The reason I can only do it in gdb is because the second word after the end of the buffer I am exploiting holds the memory address of argc. If that second word gets overwritten then the function call will not work. I compiled with the -fno-stack-protector option.

In gdb I ran:

```
run <<< (echo -e "$(python -c "print('h'*64)")aaaa\xa0\xf0\xff\xbfaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\x3b\x84\x04\x08\x37\x16\xe2\xb7")
```

the 64 h's filled the buffer, the first four a's just overflowed a word, the next four bytes are the address of argc, next 5 words (20 a's) are just overflowing. Then I put the address of win (the function I want to call) and then the old return address to exit without a segfault.

When I run this in gdb I call the win function and the process exits.
When I run this outside of gdb I get a segfault. I thought maybe the environment variables being different caused this but that is not the case I changed the environment variables in gdb to match exactly what I have outside of gdb and it still does not work.

the 7 words after the end of the buffer and before the return address are:
1: 0xb7fbb300 - Unknown
2: 0xbffff0a0 - address of argc
3: 0x00000000 - null
4: 0xb7e21637 - Return address but not the actual one that matters. (not sure why there are two)
5: 0xb7fbb000 - Unknown
6: 0xb7fbb000 - Unknown
7: 0x00000000 - Unknown

So my questions are why does this only work in gdb? and what is the significance of the address of argc to preventing a segfault? Also why do I see the return address twice? Once at the 4th word after the buffer and again at the 8th word after the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

> When I run this in gdb I call the win function and the process exits. When I run this outside of gdb I get a segfault.

GDB disables address randomization by default (use `(gdb) set disable-randomization off` to enable it under GDB).

Address randomization [was implemented](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34130/bypass-va-randomize-space-and-stack-protector) *precisely* to make stack overflow attacks more difficult, so it's not surprising that your attack is thwarted by it.

You can [disable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5194709/50617) address randomization system-wide, or you can make your attack work despite randomization (possibly by trying thousands of times with different addresses and hoping that you'll get lucky, or making the overflow payload be robust to variations in `&argc`).