# FATAL: ThreadSanitizer: unexpected memory mapping when running on Linux Kernels 6.6+

Tags: c, linux, clang, sanitizer, thread-sanitizer

#### The Problem

Recently on Linux Kernels 6.6.6 and higher it was discovered that [thread sanitizer will always lead to this error](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1716):

`FATAL: ThreadSanitizer: unexpected memory mapping 0x5c9bd4d2b000-0x5c9bd4d4b000`

I can reproduce this by writing a hello world example in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

And compiling it with tsan + running it on Arch Linux (Kernel 6.7.0) with:

```bash
clang -o play -fsanitize=thread -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer src/play.c
./play
```

This will produce the above error (with different memory addresses).

According to the github issue this will also occur in c++ files that just define an empty main() function.

#### The question

What are your options for dealing with this?

I have only recently started diving deeper into low-level operations and can barely *use* thread-sanitizer at my current knowledge levels. ASLR (which appears to be the cause of the problem) is entirely foreign to me, as are options to manipulate it and what the consequences are.

The github issue mentions 2 potential workarounds:

1. Disabling ASLR (I only found [this SO question for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194666/disable-randomization-of-memory-addresses) )
2. Reducing ASLR via `sudo sysctl vm.mmap_rnd_bits=30`

I have tried 2. and compiled + ran the example again as described, this did not resolve the issue.

I am hesitant to disable ASLR as per 1., as I wouldn't know what the implications of that are or how to "undo" that change.

What other general options to approach this are out there?

Comment: I recommend making a minimal example in C that triggers this, and then tagging "c" for visibility.

Comment: Fair point. I myself am not terribly comfortable with C and noticed the issue primarily in nim so I just started with that, but it does make sense to update this as the issue is more general. I've updated the post to include a hello world example in C and compiled it directly with clang + added the C tag as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular case, `sudo sysctl vm.mmap_rnd_bits=30` is indeed sufficient, but requires a more modern clang version than arch-linux provides by default. The version at the time of  <strike>writing</strike>  this edit (<strike>16.0.6</strike> 17.0.6) stems from  <strike>[June 2023](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-16.0.6)</strike>  [November 2023](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-17.0.6)

That release does *not* contain a fix from [`November 2023`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/7d039effc4930be9240446a4241d268a39960e0b) that allows mmap_rnd_bits having a value of 30. This fix will be available with version [18.1.0](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-18.1.0) which has only been out since the start of March this year. It may therefore still take a fair bit of time until this fix makes it into the repositories of various distros.

However, at least on arch linux you can set this value down to 28 at which point it should work again with 16.0.6 and later. However the implication this appears to have is reduced security of the system (?), it definitely beats shutting ASLR off entirely.

You can set it to 28 via `sudo sysctl vm.mmap_rnd_bits=28` (Check the value via `sudo sysctl vm.mmap_rnd_bits`).

Note that this change is *not* persistent. Once you reboot your machine, you will have to set `mmap_rnd_bits` again to 28.